# Media query for IOS not working with Position fixed background image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with IOS devices. I think the cause is Safari browser, who's not showing my background image properly. It work on any other phone except the IOS devices.

I am trying to keep Position fixed, for the image to stick and scroll down when the user scrolling but the image instead of scrolling it is just zoomed to the maximum and cant see nothing beside small chunk of the img.
The code I am using for the image -

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3){
  
    html, body{
      width:100%;
      overflow-x:hidden;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment:fixed;
      background-image: url(./phone.jpeg);
      }
```

Thank you guys really hope we can figure it out together !

Comment: I Figure that (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) fix the pixel , to match the Android version, still cant find answer about the image.